# Is py2neo caching burning me?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am running this code:

```
c = """
    match(r:XX)
    optional match(r)-[]-(m) with count(m) as mc, r match(x)
    return count(x) as all, r, mc
    """
        (snip!)
        while(True):
            tx = remote_graph.cypher.begin()
            res = remote_graph.cypher.execute(c)
            tx.rollback()
            time.sleep(15)
        (snip!)
```

I know for a fact the XX node's properties are changing every second - there a daemon running. However, when I run this, I always get the same values back in `res` **but for `r` only** - `all` is changing.  The query isn't changing. I wonder if py2neo is noticing this and not executing the query, but is returning me a cached copy?  If so, how do I stop this from happening?

EDIT - more info - I ran the above from within ipython.

Comment: What is happening in `exec_cypher`? Why `rollback()`?

Comment: @MartinPreusse Ah, sorry about that. exec_cyper (sic) is a routine we wrote that doesn't affect the query in this case.  I'll replace it.

Comment: @MartinPreusse I probably don't need the `begin()` or `rollback()` here. I have never regretted using `rollback()` even when apparently unnecessary.

Comment: `cypher.execute()` has it's own transaction, so `tx` is started but never used until `rollback()`. Anyways, doesn't help with your question.

Comment: I tried it with a minimal example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14011500/. Works for me. Are you sure about the update? What happens if you only query `MATCH (r) RETURN r`?

Comment: @MartinPreusse I am as sure as I can be about the update. The query you see above is the same one I am running in the neo4j console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97902/discussion-between-tony-ennis-and-martin-preusse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting enough, py2neo 'remembers' the node when you return the node:

```
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n
```

But when you return individual properties, they will always be updated:

```
MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n.value
```

For your query that means you have to run `my_node.pull()` when you return the same node twice in a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    q = "MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n"
    result = graph.cypher.execute(q)
    my_node = result[0][0]
    my_node.pull()
    print(my_node)
```

You can also move everything besides the `pull()` out of the loop:

```
q = "MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n"
result = graph.cypher.execute(q)
my_node = result[0][0]

while True:
    my_node.pull()
    print(my_node)
```

Here is a minimal example describing the behaviour: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14015568/

I'm not really sure why py2neo does not return updated node data when you run a new query.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say the node's attributes? Do you mean properties? Or are relationships added/removed as well?

What do you expect to get back in `r`? Judging from the query, unless the daemon you mention is adding/removing the `:XX` label to/from nodes, it'll return exactly the same nodes always.

Comment: Properties, yes. The daemon is updating the properties quite frequently.  I can look at the node using the neo4j console and I see the values changing. From my little program above, not at all. XX is a singleton so I am sure there is only one.