# py2neo and eventual consistency?

Tags: flask, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using Py2Neo 3 (v3.1.1) from a Flask debug server to access Neo4j.

The Neo4j server is a basic apt-get'd Neo4j server (3.3.3) on Ubuntu 16.04.  Py2Neo is using the Bolt port.

When a Flask request that updates the Neo4j db

```
tx = graph.begin();
....
tx.commit();
```

is followed by a request from the same client within four or more seconds, 95% of the time the results of that second query do not reflect the update that just occurred a few seconds earlier.  But if another client queries the database via the Flask server immediately after the update, it will see the updated data every time.   And it seems, if that second client does that, the probably of the first client seeing old data drops to about 75%.

I'm pretty sure that Neo4j is not running in Causal consistent mode.  (I did a simple apt-get install when I installed Neo4j.) How do I confirm this?

I believe that the Flask server is using the same Py2Neo graph object for all requests.

As you see above, the Py2Neo update request does use an explicit transaction followed by an explicit tx.commit(). But that graph object has been used for some auto commit queries as well outside the explicit transaction.

I'm not seeing any mention of "causal" or "eventual" or "cache" in the Py2Neo 3 documentation.

What suggestions do you have?

--- UPDATE 1 -----

This doesn't appear to be a Neo4j server problem.  Turning on Py2Neo.watch('neo4j.bolt') reveals that Py2Neo sends the correct request to
the Neo4j server and the updated data is being received by Py2Neo from the
Neo4j server.  But Py2Neo Cursor.data() reveals the old data is returned to the application despite the server giving Py2Neo new data.

Answer (score 0):

One can actually find a partial answer here: [Is py2neo caching burning me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273072/is-py2neo-caching-burning-me)

The referenced page suggests that you might benefit from a call to my_node.pull().  That should work, but I think you'll find that's actually inefficient because it results in another non-trivial request to the db despite the correct value being already received efficiently from the db one (or more) times and then ignored.

As an alternative consider using the Python driver that Neo Technologies publishes+supports and that Py2Neo is using.   If you do this, you will lose some of the features of Py2Neo (ex. OGM), but you'll have better control over the conversation between your app and the Neo4j server and one less, possibly buggy, layer in your stack.  You can find info about this Python driver and other options [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/).